# Same ISP, same place but different wireless modem signals

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, signal-strength

I have 2 3G usb modems. 1 is ZTE and the other one is Huawei, both use a same ISP at same place. But the problem is that Huawei's device gets 3 signals while ZTE's device seldom get a single signal.
Someone told me there's a chip inside the usb modems which become weaker after a year or so, and the reception gets weaker. I want to know the reason and the possible solution.

Comment: One is better than the other. It really is that simple.

Comment: Newer devices often have multiple antennas inside using them for [antenna diversity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_diversity). This can significantly increase the signal quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have even known with such an issue is to either make a warranty claim (depends on whether its still within it) or sadly put up with it.
Then again, technology standards have come a long way in the past few years, so this may not necessarly be the case with some newer, more expensive brands.